# How to use custom metrics in Keras model while using Grid Search CV?

Tags: machine-learning, keras, scikit-learn, conv-neural-network, hyperparameters

I want to use R2 (Coefficient of determination) as metrics in my Keras model. For that, I have already defined a function (coeff_determination). This function as a metric works well without Grid Search CV but with grid search cv it gives an error like "The model is not configured to compute the accuracy. You should pass `metrics=["accuracy"]` to the `model.compile()` method". The code is given below.

```
def create_model():

    #CNN Architecture - Model 7
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Convolution1D(filters=10, kernel_size=12, activation="relu", kernel_initializer="glorot_uniform", input_shape=(X_train.shape[1],1)))
    model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=4, strides=2))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(Convolution1D(filters=16, kernel_size=12, activation='relu', kernel_initializer="glorot_uniform"))
    model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=3, strides=2))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(Convolution1D(filters=22, kernel_size=12, activation='relu', kernel_initializer="glorot_uniform"))
    model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=3, strides=2))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(Convolution1D(filters=28, kernel_size=12, activation='relu', kernel_initializer="glorot_uniform"))
    model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=4, strides=2))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(Convolution1D(filters=34, kernel_size=12, activation='relu', kernel_initializer="glorot_uniform"))
    model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=3, strides=2))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(Convolution1D(filters=40, kernel_size=12, activation='relu', kernel_initializer="glorot_uniform"))
    model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=3, strides=2))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(Flatten())
    #model.add(Dropout(0.35))
    model.add(Dense(130, activation='relu'))
    #model.add(Dropout(0.35))
    model.add(Dense(130, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(1, activation='linear'))
    history = History()
    model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error',optimizer= Adam(lr=0.0001), metrics=[coeff_determination])
    #model.fit(X_train,y_train, validation_data=(X_test,y_test), epochs=400, batch_size=30, callbacks=[history])
    return model

def coeff_determination(y_true, y_pred):
    SS_res = K.sum(K.square(y_true - y_pred))
    SS_tot = K.sum(K.square(y_true - K.mean(y_true)))
    return (1 - SS_res / (SS_tot + K.epsilon()))
# to reprduce the same results next time
seed = 7
np.random.seed(seed)
# Creating Keras model with Scikit learn wrap-up
model = KerasClassifier(build_fn=create_model, verbose=0)
# define the grid search parameters
batch_size = [20,30,40,80]
epochs = [100,200,300,400]
# Using make scorer to convert metric r_2 to a scorer
my_scorer = make_scorer(r2_score, greater_is_better=True)

# passing dictionaries of parameters to the GridSearchCV
param_grid = dict(batch_size=batch_size, epochs=epochs)
grid = GridSearchCV(estimator=model, scoring=my_scorer, param_grid=param_grid, n_jobs=1, cv=3)
grid_result = grid.fit(X_train, y_train)
# summarizing the results
print("Best: %f using %s" % (grid_result.best_score_, grid_result.best_params_))
means = grid_result.cv_results_['mean_test_score']
stds = grid_result.cv_results_['std_test_score']
params = grid_result.cv_results_['params']
for mean, stdev, param in zip(means, stds, params):
    print("%f (%f) with: %r" % (mean, stdev, param))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to feed your custom scoring function as the input for `scoring` param to `GridSearchCV` otherwise it will look out for the default estimator's scoring method which is accuracy.

From [Documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html#sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV):

> **`scoring:`** str, callable, list/tuple or dict, default=None
>   A single str (see The scoring parameter: defining model evaluation rules) or a callable (see Defining your scoring strategy from metric functions) to evaluate the predictions on the test set.
>
> For evaluating multiple metrics, either give a list of (unique) strings or a dict with names as keys and callables as values.
>
> NOTE that when using custom scorers, each scorer should return a single value. Metric functions returning a list/array of values can be wrapped into multiple scorers that return one value each.
>
> See Specifying multiple metrics for evaluation for an example.
>
> If None, the estimator’s score method is used.

Comment: I have already tried this as you can see in my code snippet a 'my_scorer' right below the grid search parameters (batch_size, epochs). I defined my_scorer using the make_scorer from GridSearchCV and r2_score from scikit-learn. It was passed onto GridSearchCV as you said but still, I was getting this error. One more thing, what about the metrics in the CNN model? Am I supposed to feed the same custom scoring function (i.e. coeff_determination) to CNN metrics and GridSearchCV scoring parameter?

Comment: I couldn't see `my_scorer` being fed to `GridSearchCV`, can update your code with the version which you were talking about?

Comment: Please check my updated code now. It works but I still have some doubts regarding the CODE implementation because it always gives -ve `r2_score` for all of the possible models (i.e. 16) using different batch sizes and epochs. Whereas I got good +ve `r2_score` for several of them when I tried on my own without `GridSearchCV` using the same CNN architecture as shown above.